# ASP.Net Modal Popup position

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, positioning, modalpopupextender

I have a web user control with a modal popup extender in it. the modal popup contains an `asp:Panel` control in it. This panel contains other controls.
I'd like to make the modal popup scroll as the user scrolls the page. (position:absolute)

- Tried to set `X` and `Y` properties of the popup extender. it changes  the `X` and `Y` properties of the popup. But still: `position:fixed`
- Tried to set the Panel's CssClass to (.ModalWindow) which has the following defiition: `.ModalWindow{position:absolute;}` But the `position:fixed` overrides it.
- Tried to wrap the `asp:Panel` in a div: `<div style="position:absolute;">` But still no luck.

Comment: What "popup extender" are you using? Is it a standard thing?

Comment: @Niklas: It's the ModalPopupExtender of AjaxControlToolkit. Guess I can call it the standard one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

`.ModalWindow {position: absolute!important;`}

The `!important` override is a really handy trick, particularly when working with ASP.NET controls.

Here's a bit more about it:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/